# QXcbConnection: XCB error: 145 (Unknown) Error message starting Spyder with MobaXTerm Qt5

Tags: qt5, spyder

I'm seeing the following error message when starting Spyder over a remote connection through MobaXTerm:

```
$ spyder
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 145 (Unknown), sequence: 171, resource id: 0, major code: 139 (Unknown), minor code: 20
```

Spyder still appears to work normally, but the error message pops up every time. A search on this error blames Qt5 and says there's no fix for X11 connections. I'm using Python 3.5.4, Spyder 3.2.3, and MobaXTerm Personal Edition v10.7 Build 3650 connecting to a system running RHEL 6.6.

**How can I avoid the error message?**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After trying the methods I could find on various websites:

- `conda install pyopengl` on the base python installation
- Adding both `from OpenGL import GL` and `import ctypes; ctypes.CDLL("libGL.so.1", mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)` to `site-packages/spyder/app/start.py`
- various Qt environment variable settings

**EDIT:**

I was finally able to stop the error messages by disabling only the "RANDR" MobaXTerm X11 extension:

[image: X11_Settings]

Interestingly, the MobaXTerm documentation also has this extension disabled in the settings screenshots.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. works with MobaXTerm X11 RANDR extension uncheck.

Comment: Your Mobaxterm XRANDR uncheck fix.. I wish would have found it earlier. I wasted many hours working multiple things vnc4server/tightvnc/lightdm/x11vnc/gdm3/zoc/putty and what not.
I gave up on Mobaxterm, bcz rviz and most of qt apps were crashing in it.
And then I saw your this post. and end of all that crap.
A big Thanks.

Comment: @ashish Thanks. It was a big frustration for me too. I'm happy to help

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue when running rviz for ros2 from the Windows 10 WSL2 Ubuntu 20.10 Terminal with the command:

```
ros2 launch turtlebot3_bringup rviz2.launch.py
```

I tried unchecking the RANDR extension in MobaXterm to no effect. I was finally able to resolve the issue and launch rviz after issuing the following command:

```
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=0
```

and then re-issuing the ros2 launch command above.